# __get__() of a method/function in Python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that I am trying to understand, and even with the existing answers, I really couldn't understand the purpose of the following code, Can someone please help me in understanding the same?

I have already looked a various relevant questions ( `__get__()` ) here and I couldnt find specific answers. I understand that the class below is trying to create a method on the fly ( possibly we get to this class from a `__getattr__()` method which fails to find an attribute ) and return the method to the caller. I have commented right above the lines of code I need understanding with.

```
class MethodGen(object):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        method = self.method_gen(name)
        if method:
           return self.method_gen(name)


    def method_gen(self, name):

        def method(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Creating a method here")

        # Below are the two lines of code I need help understanding with
        method.__name__ = name
        setattr(self, name, method.__get__(self))

        return method
```

If I am not wrong, the `method()` function's attribute `__name__` has been set, but in `setattr()` function, the attribute of the class `MethodGen`, `name` is set to what ?

Answer (score 1):

This question really intrigued me. The two answers provided didn't seem to tell the whole story.  What bothered me was the fact that in this line:

```
setattr(self, name, method.__get__(self))
```

the code is not setting things up so that `method.__get__` *Will* be called at some point.  Rather, `method.__get__` is actually *Being Called*!  But isn't the idea that this `__get__` method will be called when a particular attribute of an object, an instance of MethodGen in this case, is actually referenced?  If you read the docs, this is the impression you get...that an attribute is linked to a Descriptor that implements `__get__`, and that implementation determines what gets returned when that attribute is referenced.  But again, that's not what's going on here.  This is all happening before that point.  So what IS really going on here?

The answer lies [HERE](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods).  The key language is this:

> To support method calls, functions include the `__get__()` method for
>   binding methods during attribute access. This means that all functions
>   are non-data descriptors which return bound methods when they are
>   invoked from an object.

`method.__get__(self)` is exactly what's being described here.  So what `method.__get__(self)` is actually doing is returning a reference to the `"method" function` that is bound to `self`.  Since in our case, `self` is an instance of `MethodGen`, this call is returning a reference to the `"method" function` that is bound to an instance of `MethodGen`. In this case, the `__get__` method has nothing to do with the act of referencing an attribute.  Rather, this call is turning a function reference into a method reference!

So now we have a reference to a method we've created on the fly. But how do we set it up so it gets called at the right time, when an attribute with the right name is referenced on the instance it is bound to?  That's where the `setattr(self, name, X)` part comes in.  This call takes our new method and binds it to the attribute with name `name` on our instance.

All of the above then is why:

```
setattr(self, name, method.__get__(self))
```

is adding a new method to `self`, the instance of the `MethodGen` class on which `method_gen` has been called.

The `method.__name__ = name` part is not all that important.  Executing just the line of code discussed above gives you all the behavior you really want. This extra step just attaches a name to our new method so that code that asks for the name of the method, like code that uses introspection to write documentation, will get the right name.  It is the instance attribute's name...the name passed to `setattr`...that really matters, and really "names" the method.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, never seen this done before, seems tough to maintain (probably will make some fellow developers want to hang you).

I changed some code so you can see a little more of what is happening.

```
class MethodGen(object):

    def method_gen(self, name):
        print("Creating a method here")
        def method(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Calling method")
            print(args) # so we can see what is actually being outputted

        # Below are the two lines of code I need help understanding with
        method.__name__ = name # These the method name equal to name (i.e. we can call the method this way) 
        # The following is adding the new method to the current class.
        setattr(self, name, method.__get__(self)) # Adds the method to this class

        # I would do: setattr(self, name, method) though and remove the __get__

        return method # Returns the emthod

m = MethodGen()
test = m.method_gen("my_method") # I created a method in MethodGen class called my_method
test("test") # It returned a pointer to the method that I can use
m.my_method("test") # Or I can now call that method in the class.
m.method_gen("method_2")
m.method_2("test2")
```

Comment: So, the `settattr()` function is just trying to make the now newly created an attribute of the class `MethodGen` ?

Comment: Correct that's what it is doing.

Comment: You say "I would do: setattr(self, name, method) though and remove the `__get__`".  You can't do that.  As my answer explains, it is the call to `__get__` that causes the attribute you're adding to the instance to be a **method** rather than a simple **function**.  Only with the `__get__` would this new method be passed the right `this` when it is called on the instance it's been bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the class below:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print("hi")

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```

`bar` is a *class* attribute that has a function as its value. Because `function` implements the descriptor protocol, however, accessing it as `Foo.bar` or `f.bar` does *not* immediately return the function itself; it causes the function's `__get__` method to be invoked, and *that* returns either the original function (as in `Foo.bar`) or a *new* value of type `instancemethod` (as in `f.bar`). `f.bar()` is evaluated as `Foo.bar.__get__(f, Foo)()`.

`method_gen` takes the function named `method`, and attaches an *actual* method retrieved by calling the function's `__get__` method to an object. The intent is so that something like this works:

```
>>> m = MethodGen()
>>> n = MethodGen()
>>> m.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MethodGen' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> n.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MethodGen' object has no attribute 'foo'
>>> m.method_gen('foo')
<function foo at 0x10465c758>
>>> m.foo()
Creating a method here
>>> n.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MethodGen' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Initially, `MethodGen` does not have any methods other than `method_gen`. You can see the exception raised when attempting to invoke a method named `foo` on either of two instances. Calling `method_gen`, however, attaches a new method to *just* that particular instance. After calling `m.method_gen("foo")`, `m.foo()` calls the method defined by `method_gen`. That call does not affect other instances of `MethodGen` like `n`.

Comment: What you say before and just after your first code block seem to contradict each other.  If "When you call a method, you are really calling the "thing" returned by the method's `__get__` method. ", then wouldn't the equivalent to `f.bar()` be `f.bar.__get__(f, Foo)()` ?

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the answer. It is clear to me now !

Comment: Why are the instance and the relevant class part of the call ? i.e. in `f.bar.__get__(f, Foo)`

Comment: @Steve Yeah, I need to reword that more precisely. The short version is: what you think of as a method is really just a function-valued class attribute. Accessing the attribute triggers the function's `__get__` method, which returns the thing you usually think of as a method.

Comment: @chepner.  I was trying to see it this way, but it bothered me that `__get__` is being called during setup of the instance, not later on when an attribute on the instance is being referenced.  That pulled me down the rabbit's hole that led to the answer I provide.  `__get__` in this case has nothing to do with referencing an attribute.  Rather, it is actually turning a function into a method.

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's how methods works: accessing a class-attribute function as an instance attribute causes its `__get__` method to return the *method* you expect. Here, it's being called explicitly to attach the method proper to a specific instance. Note that `m.foo` is no longer a function; it's an instance of `instancemethod`.

Comment: You say "accessing it as `Foo.bar` or `f.bar` does not immediately return the function itself; it causes the function's `__get__` method to be invoked", but that's not true.  The `__get__` method is being called explicitly, and the result of it assigned to `f.bar`, as your second paragraph explains.  The `__get__` method in question here isn't invoked when `f.bar` is accessed. Your statement "`f.bar()` is evaluated as `Foo.bar.__get__(f, Foo)()`." is not true either.  Your second paragraph seems to have it right.  I'd suggest you just say that.

Comment: @Steve In *normal* usage, that's true. However, `method` is not an attribute; it's a local function being defined in the local scope of `method_gen`, so `__get__` *has* to be called explicitly to get the "method version" of `method`.

Comment: @chepner, I don't know what you mean by "normal usage".  I'm only talking about this specific case.  What you just said is all true, but what you say in your answer is not correct.  Again, the `__get__` method is not called at all when accessing `f.bar`.  Both of your statements that I called out say that it is.   `__get__` is only called when `method_gen` is called.